# Debian: I'm unable to log in + can't boot properly after system backup and restore

Tags: permissions, backup, lvm, login, restore

I used to copy my system/config files from `lvm-based` `/dev/mapper/devuan--vg-root` + `/dev/mapper/devuan--vg-home` partitions into external storage and moved them to a fresh `btrfs` partition after installing `Windows`. Unfortunately, I forgot to copy the rest from the `lvm-based` `/dev/mapper/devuan--vg-var` + `/dev/mapper/devuan--vg-tmp` partitions.

### Problems

After I set and installed `grub`, I was able to `boot` the system, but:

1. The system stops loading at the following error message:

   ```
   fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
   /bin/fsck.btrfs: /dev/mapper/devuan--vg-home does not exist
   /bin/fsck.btrfs: /dev/mapper/devuan--vg-tmp does not exist
   /bin/fsck.btrfs: /dev/mapper/devuan--vg-var does not exist
   fsck exited with status code 8
   ```
2. I got other errors as well, due to the missing `/var/*` folders for
   some servers such as `cron` and `exim4` - at that
   point, I managed to create them manually, as well as copying the
   required files of `/var/lib/dpkg/*` and `/var/cache/dpkg/*` folders
   from `xubuntu` `livecd`.

The only solution I found for the `fsck` errors, is to `touch /fastboot`, but this is limited to the next `boot` (i.e not permanent solution).

### Questions

1. How can I disable `lvm` partitions' check on `boot` (I mean uninstall `lvm` completely) permanently?
2. What tool could you suggest for `backing up and restoring` the `system + user data` from `lvm` partitions' filesystem, *more efficiently* in the future?

Comment: This feels like you forgot to copy file permissions (either during the backup or the restore). What is result of `ls -l /bin/bash`?

Comment: In your question please also provide the same `ls -l`, but this time from your backup.

Comment: Do you still have your backup? I'd like to see the result of running `ls -l` for the file `/bin/bash` as stored in your backup, to ascertain whether or not your backup has any additional value we can extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've failed to restore the file ownerships and permissions for the OS files. I'm quite impressed the system boots and allows root to log in.

If you took good backups you should be able to wipe and restore properly. Otherwise you'll need to reinstall from scratch and then restore the files from your home directory.

It should theoretically be possible to reapply the `deb` packages you already have installed, but without the package database in `/var` that's next to impossible.

---

To answer your specific questions you've added,

1. Reinstall or restore from a known-good backup. You don't have the backup so that leaves you only one choice.
2. You have no database of installed packages so you would have to pick off the LVM tools (programs, libraries, configuration files) one by one. See #1
3. There are many options. Here are a few

   - [`rsnapshot`](http://rsnapshot.org/) and its dependency `rsync`
   - `tar`
   - [`duplicity`](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) and [`duplicati`](https://www.duplicati.com/)
   - [Veeam Agent - Free](https://www.veeam.com/linux-backup-free-download.html) (commercial software but zero financial cost). I use this professionally and at home. I am not affiliated to Veeam

Next time I'd suggest you install local tools under either `/usr/local/` (for example `/usr/local/bin/wais`) or `/opt`. You can then copy them off to a new system trivially.

Comment: ok. but how can I fix the permissions in order to allow non-root users to log in?

Comment: @Kais I've already answered that.

Comment: I can't reinstall from scratch, as I will lose many tools I installed manually.

Comment: I think reinstalling from scratch is the best solution for my case (I need to get back to Debian. BTW have you heard of the 'stretch' version?) - I backed up [`/home` `/usr` `/root` `/etc`] within tar archive, so I will investigate them to update all my configs manually + re-install the binaries. Thanks for your help.